# Having trouble learning how to use __init__ statements

Tags: python

The code is creating a function that adds a value to the existing list at a certain index. I am having trouble printing print cases to check my code. I am assuming it's a problem in my inheritance class but I am not too sure how to fix the print statement?

```
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Any, Optional


class Pair:
    def __int__(self, first: any, rest: Optional[Pair]) -> None:
        self.first = first
        self.rest = rest


LinkedList = Optional[Pair]


def add(lst: LinkedList, index: int, value: Any) -> LinkedList:
    if index == 0:
        return Pair(value, lst)

    if lst is None:
        raise IndexError

    return Pair(lst.first, add(lst.rest, index - 1, value))
```

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
print(add(my_list, 1, "hi"))
```

I get errors saying 'list' obeject has no attribute 'first'

Comment: Hi Bob; this has nothing to do with `__init__`. It's just that you pass in an actual python list into your function, but that function wants to operate on a linked list object. Also, there's no inheritance here.

Comment: I'm confused between a linkedlist and python list. Could you elaborate on that too? Please and thank you

Comment: As @Lagerbaer says, `my_list` is a vanilla `list` (a variable of type `list`).  But `add` here wants a variable of type `LinkedList`.

Comment: I didn't read the question, but you have `__int__` in your code, instead of `__init__`

Comment: How would I run test cases for a code like this?